# mySQL - Get Unique ID

Tags: mysql

I have a table (TransTbl) that consists of 2 fields (Transaction ID & Transaction Date).

Examples of the transaction ID are 202101, 202102, 202103, etc. It is constructed using current year + maximum record count in TransTbl.

As the table is accessed by many users at the same time, there is a possibility that the maximum record count may not be unique. (E.g. same transaction ID for different records).

Is there any way to avoid the above situation as each transaction ID should be unique? Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: With which technology you are using your Database like PHP, Java, Ruby, etc?

Comment: I'll be using PHP

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PHP you can also use `strtoupper(uniqid());` to create a random unique id each time.
If you are not specific with the format you describe

If you are specific with your format:

Database queries are always executed in the FIFO process. So if multiple users are accessing the table same time only one query will be executed at a time at your row count will be increased